# How to see which CPU is on the current machine?

Tags: macos, cpu, hardware

I'm looking on the 'safe' [Cflags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFLAGS) on the Gentoo Wiki, and I want to figure out how to [see which CPU is on a specific machine](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Safe_Cflags#GCC_Version_and_CPU).

On Gentoo I see you can get this with

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

but on Mac I get

> No such file or directory

What is the equivalent for OS X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From terminal, you'll want to start with `system_profiler`

```
 system_profiler SPHardwareDataType
```

Also, much more data is available from `ioreg` but you'll need to parse the output (which can arrive as XML if you prefer) to get things like actual bus and clock frequency of each core.

Answer (score 4):

On the other hand, if you don't want processor name, speed, the number of processors, etc but you're interested in the model number, you might want to give `sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string` a try, eg.

```
$ sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7600  @ 3.06GHz
```

Comment: Nice example of sysctl!

Comment: Thanks @bmike, and nice example of speeding up and filtering through `system_profiler`, I might add! :)